# TikZ in section heading in moderncv

Tags: tikz-pgf, moderncv

I was experimenting quite randomly and wondered about inserting some TikZ in section headings.

With an `article`, this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\my}{\tikz\draw (0,0) circle (5pt);}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction \protect\my}
\end{document}
```

works.

But if I use `moderncv`, this

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{tikz}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\newcommand{\my}{\tikz\draw (0,0) circle (5pt);}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction \protect\my}
\end{document}
```

does not work.

Why?

Comment: Your example is incomplete: You have to add `\firstname{User}` and `\familyname{9137}` to the preamble such that `moderncv` does not complain about these missing definitions. Then, the error is not really related to `moderncv` but to the fact that `moderncv` loads the `hyperref` package. You get the same error with the `article` class when adding `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a conflict between `hyperref` and `tikz`, and `moderncv` loads `hyperref`.

The solution involves using `\texorpdfstring` to define your command.

Something like this:

```
\texorpdfstring{tikz code}{alternative (empty)}
```

Your MWE should be as follows:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{tikz}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\newcommand{\my}{\texorpdfstring{\tikz\draw (0,0) circle (5pt);}{}}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction \protect\my}
\end{document}
```